# How socket.io and REST handle request

Tags: node.js, rest, socket.io

I have a nodejs app and now facing spamming issue. When I try to spam my socket api the app will down and can't get any response from server anymore. But if I changed to REST api, the app is still working well even I keep spamming the api endpoint.

Socket api (Only one connection):

```
// Get client message
socket.on('message', function (data) {
    socket.emit('response', "Hi");  // Emit message to client 
}
```

REST api with express:

```
app = express();
app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.json({msg: "Hi"});  // Response message to client
}
```

So my question is how these two handle requests? What's the difference between them in low level implementation? Really need help on this, I have studied lots of reference online and networking book, but still can't find any answer or topic talk about how socket and REST API handle request in low level implementation. And how those spamming requests queued?

**EDIT:**

Spamming code:

```
// Socket spamming app:
var socket = io.connect('ws://localhost:9001');
socket.on('connect', function (socket) {
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)
        socket.emit('message',"hi server");
});
socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    // won't receive any msg after socket down during spamming
    console.log(msg) 
});



// REST API endpoint spamming
const request = require('request');
function spam() {
  const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.post({
      url: `http://localhost:8080/test`,
    }, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
        ...
    })
  });
  console.log(a) // Every responses works fine
}
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  spam();
}
```

Comment: If you invoke the REST API via a safe operation, i.e. `GET`, chances are high that the requested resource is being cached on the client side (or by an intermediary server) and any consecutive calls are handled by your local cache instead of really sending the request to the server to start with. This is one of the properties that allowed the real Web to grow to its size we have today. Your socket example, in contrast, will have to process every request though as a client lacks the capability of caching such responses and therefore can't serve the response from its local cache directly.

Comment: But what if i spam without browser? Did it cached also? Currently I spam my REST api endpoint by a nodejs application with request.

Comment: Any help on this question ?

Comment: Caching is not limited or tide to the browser. The easiest thing to test out whether caching is active or not is to add a log-statement to the respective server response and see whether the log-line is printed in case of an invocation. If you don't see a log-line for your "REST" invocation, than the response was surely served by a cache.

Comment: I tested my app is not doing caching. Every responses are served by server. And what if the API is POST? I think there is no way to do any caching for POST right?

Comment: Yeah, any unsafe request will lead to an invalidation of the stored responses for the given URI in the cache. As your issue obviously doesn't seem to be caused by caching, maybe it is due to the usage of a single vs. multiple threads? Typical HTTP frameworks usually handle incoming requests in a thread pool while in the socket case, threading support usually has done by the developer

Comment: Does nodejs implement thread pool to handle incoming request too?